# Sort a group of data based on a column

Tags: linux, sorting

I have an input file that contains following data:

```
1 2 3 4
  4   6
  8   9
      10
2 1 5 7
  3
3 4 2 9
  2   7
      11
```

I'm trying to `sort` the group of data based on the third column and get such an output:

```
2 1 5 7
  3
1 2 3 4
  4   6
  8   9 
      10
3 4 2 9
  2   7
      11
```

Could you tell me how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

```
sort -nk3r
```

will sort in reverse order based on 3rd column. Note however, that this outputs

```
2 1 5 7
1 2 3 4
3 4 2 9
      10
      11
  2   7
  3
  4   6
  8   9
```

because of the way bash sort functions, and this produces a different result than the output you posted, but correct according to the question.